# Invisible Plane Lines In Top View Outside Of Edit Mode

Tags: interface

When viewing planes directly from above/the side, when outside of edit mode, the lines that represent them become invisible, even when selected.  Going into Preferences -> Interface and changing the Line Width to Thick does not resolve the issue.  Watching tutorials using older versions of Blender, this does not seem to occur.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just realized I could view them in wireframe view.  Please disregard.

[image]